# Using a Switch to Define Custom Validators in Angular 2

Tags: angular, switch-statement, custom-validators

I am having trouble using switches to define custom validators in Angular 2.

I have created a custom validator using multiple callbacks as seen below. This works just fine:

```js
function validateThrow(c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null {
  // if the input is not simply a number, it must begin with one of the multiplier characters or b
  if (isNaN(c.value) && c.value.charAt(0).toLowerCase() != 't' && c.value.charAt(0).toLowerCase() != 'd' && c.value.charAt(0).toLowerCase() != 'b') {
    return {'tooLong': true};
  } 
    return null
}
```

However I am finding that this is leading to callbacks within callbacks as I make my code more complex. Therefore I would rather use a switch. It is my understanding that promises might help mitigate these issues, but I don't understand promises at the moment. When I try to use a switch I am not getting any errors (either in the browser or my IDE) but the code is not doing anything to affect my template as it should. Below is an example of a switch that I feel should accomplish the same thing and yet is not working:

```js
function validateThrowSwitch (c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null {
    switch (c.value) {
      case isNaN(c.value) && c.value.charAt(0).toLowerCase() != 't' && c.value.charAt(0).toLowerCase() != 'd' && c.value.charAt(0).toLowerCase() != 'b':
        return {'tooLong': true};
      default: return null;
    }
```

Why would the second example of code not respond the same way as the first in the context of custom validators in Angular 2?

Comment: i think you have misuse the switch-statement.

Comment: `Promise` is for async calls. I haven't seen anything async in your code. I also don't get what you mean by multiple callbacks, I haven't found anything like that in your question.